# How to extract audio features using Accord.net C#

Tags: c#, audio, nuget, accord.net

i want to extract features of input audio files in C#. (frequencies , length , etc)

for this task i was trying to use **Accord.audio** nuget library. But I've failed to find a how to guide or working example that suits my need.

**Can you please show me how to extract audio features of a file using accord.audio nuget library.**
For an example, when i input "song.mp3" file, i want a requency array , decibal array , length etc feature of "song.mp3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for some tutorials on how to do stuff with **Acoord.net**, I think [this](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Sample-applications) is all you need.

and I don't think that C# is the best choice when it comes for Sound preprocessing related stuff. If you are willing to use Python, You can make use of **[Librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/)** for all your Sound Preprocessing and feature Extraction things, Dump the datasets into json file or whatever and Use it from C#.